# How to get C-Style string functions working?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make function that counts vowels and consonants in a c-style string, as well as change the string to uppercase. Whenever I run the function to it always returns with "0". What can I do to fix this? Thanks for the help.

```
 int Count(const char[], int counter){

 counter= 0;
 for(int i = 0; line.length[]; i++){

    if(line[i] == 'a' || line[i] == 'e' || line[i] == 'i' ||      line[i] == 'o'     || line[i] == 'u'){

    --counter;
}

void upperCase(const char[]){

for(int i = 0; line.length[]; i++) {
toupper(line[i]); }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your code is pretty long, please try to produce a [mcve]. You may also be interested in [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for yourself. Your question is more likely to produce good answers if you nail down the problem for yourself. See also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

`Count()` did not return 0. You just didn't take its return value for printing.

And in `UpperCase()` and `LowerCase()`, you should assign the return value of `toupper()` and `tolower()` back into `text[i]`. That is,

```
text[i] = toupper(text[i]);
```

Comment: Yes. And in order to do that the passing parameter should not be constant.

Answer (score 1):

Vowels and consonants will always be zero because you are passing them by value, hence their values will not change to fix this you should pass them by reference and so the functions prototypes will be

```
int Count(const char[], int&); //function heading int Count(const char text[], int& a)
int Count2(const char[], int&); //function heading int Count2(const char text[], int &b)
```

Also in the functions definition you are decrementing the values? They should be incremented.